# MarkLogic - Enabling stemming will also search for American / British spelling

Tags: search, marklogic, stemming

MarkLogic 9.0.8.2

We have business requirements to support American/British words in search queries like

- fiber or fibre
- color or colour

SO if we enable stemming at database level will solve this problem or we need to configure more to make it work?

Stemming
https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/stemming

Comment: Does the data have a mixture of Amarican/British words, or is the data using consistent language but you want to be able to resolve searches from either American or British search terms, or both?

Comment: Thanks MH for your reply
Yes, we have mix of American/British words and want to get result for both if search either of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, enabling stemming on the database would be the easiest way to achieve what you are looking to do.

Below is some code that you can use to quickly experiment and verify that it will work for you:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
(: enable stemmed searches :)
import module namespace admin = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/admin" at "/MarkLogic/admin.xqy";

let $config := admin:get-configuration()
return
  (: experiment with various settings: off, basic, advanced, decompounding :) 
  admin:database-set-stemmed-searches($config, xdmp:database("Documents"), "basic") 
  ! admin:save-configuration(.)
;

(: insert two test documents with different spelling for color :)
("color","colour") ! xdmp:document-insert("/"||.||".xml", <doc>{.}</doc>)
;

(: search and see what is returned :)
cts:search(doc(), cts:word-query("colour"))
```